# Typescript is "over infering"

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code:

```
interface classAOptions {
    optionA?: string
}

abstract class Base<TOptions extends classAOptions = classAOptions> {
    protected options: TOptions;

    constructor(options: TOptions) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    updateOptions(options: Partial<TOptions>) {}
}

interface classBOptions extends classAOptions {
    optionB?: string
}

class Extending<TOptions extends classBOptions = classBOptions> extends Base<TOptions> {
    constructor(options: TOptions) {
        super(options);
    }
}

const bInstance = new Extending({
    optionB: 'test'
});

/** Why can't I see "optionA" here? */
bInstance.updateOptions({
    optionA: 'something else'
});
```

The problem is, that if I create a `class` with a generic option method, to have the possibility, to expand it further, typescript somehow infers the generic on instantiation, and forgets about the rules I set.

In the above situation, typescript, somehow, infers that my `bInstance`, is a type of `Extending` with the generic set to an object which only defines the `optionB` property. Because of this, later on, when I try to use the `updateOptions` method, inherited from the abstract `Base` class, the input parameter only accepts the `optionB` parameter.

How could I achieve, the following things:

1. when I use the `updateOptions` method from the `bInstance`, I would like to allow the usage of both the `classAOptions` and `classBOptions` interface - in other words, I would like to be able to set the `optionA` property, even though it was not set at instantiaton
2. I would like to achieve this, without having to extend the `updateOptions` function in `Extending` class

Is this possible somehow?

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQGzgZ0wQQPIAOYwA9iJsgN4BQydyJRpIOA-AFzKZhSgDm1AL7VqcAEbcoiMKgzZkAISwQAPABVCxMhQgAPSCAAmFdFlybmFALyyz%20JtoB8VWvQJQSkBJEMMH5Tg1-TABuEXpUbR4AV28SKAAKRi0A5CCUzABKFwiIsAALYEwAOmTLZBsy7TCI4Vc6aIJDOEgLbSTgzgAFOChiODR1NvJHbMphOtBIWEQUU2wFYZ19CCMTOXNgnPoqkAUOLh5%20IRF5igBRFaN%20Ia29A2NbBaWKp8xF4Od71celTFV0pZnDQIggolBYmB4h0MoElmN6rlMI1oDDLJkavQJqcosgxABJchgOAgJCvEAQADuyEuD34CRBO38Ck4AHJINxWUIMSIAPQAKn5yAA6vkAJ6oEns5D4rgQFAAIl2OAVyHy0AgrGQ-N51AJRJJSGKjWarWCDMRyrZmBIAFsIAV%20MgIGh-lzBBigA).

Answer (score 1):

You just have to specify the generic parameter when instantiating:

```
const bInstance = new Extending<classBOptions>({
    optionB: 'test'
});

/** Why can't I see "optionA" here? */
bInstance.updateOptions({
    optionA: 'something else'
});
```

Comment: that's also something I would have liked to avoid - although it indeed works that way, but I don't see why that would be necessary, as I explicitly told at class definition time, that if the generic is ommited, treat it as `classBOptions`. This way, I have to import the type of the option as well, when instantiating a basic class of this type:|

Comment: I don't think the default generic parameter does something there, TS has to give the `Extending` class some type upon instantiation. If TS did what you wanted it, ANYTHING could be the type of your `bInstance` object, because every type extends your `classBOptions`, since both of their properties are optional.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the definition of `updateOptions`:

```
updateOptions(options: Partial<TOptions & classAOptions>) {}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQGzgZ0wQQPIAOYwA9iJsgN4BQydyJRpIOA-AFzKZhSgDm1AL7VqcAEbcoiMKgzZkAISwQAPABVCxMhQgAPSCAAmFdFlybmFALyyz%20JtoB8VWvQJQSkBJEMMH5Tg1-TABuEXpUbR4AV28SKAAKRi0A5CCUzABKFwiIsAALYEwAOmTLZBsy7TCI4Vc6aIJDOEgLbSTgzgAFOChiODR1NvJkADJbbHsMx2zKYTrQSFhEFFNsBWGdfQgjEzlzYJz6KpAFDi4efiERNYoAUW2jfiHDvQNjCcwNw5tb7%20nkG8dh8lJhVOlLM4aBEEFEoLEwPEOhlAptZvVcphGtBkZZMjV6PMblFkGIAJLkMBwEBICrIEAQADuyAe734CWhx38Ck4AHJINxeUJ8SIAPQAKnFyAA6vkAJ6oan85BkrgQFAAIhOOA1yHy0AgrGQ4tF1HJlOpSGKjWarWCHIx2r5mBIAFsIAV%20IC0GChYJ8UA)

Comment: in that case, if I then define a new class, `FutherExtending`, which extends `Extending`, I will still need to define an `updateOptions` in the `Extending` class, or I will lose the options defined by the middle class.

Comment: are you sure you need generics here? Why not just use `classAOptions` in the constructor and updateOptions etc.